# View nested objects under Tinker

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, tinker

On Laravel Tinker when I run this:

```
>>> $customers = App\Customer::all();
```

I get a list of objects such as:

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#811
 all: [
   App\Customer {#815
     id: 3,
     favorite: 6,
     user: App\User {#232 ...11},
     zip: 11221
  }
  ...
]
```

My question is how do I expand the `user` value where it has `{#232 ...11}`?

Answer (score 1):

the tinker function of artisan is based almost entirely off of the psysh

see: https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/

also: https://psysh.org/

inside psysh is a command called dump, dump is an implementation of symfony's var-dumper a newer kind of var_dump.

```
dump -h
```

shows:

> Usage:  dump [--depth DEPTH] [-a|--all] [--]
>
> Arguments:  target     A target object or primitive to dump.
>
> Options:  --depth    Depth to parse. (default: 10)  --all (-a) Include 
> private and protected methods and properties.
>
> Help:  Dump an object or primitive.    This is like var_dump but way 
> awesomer.    e.g.
>
> >>> dump $_ 
> >>> dump $someVar 
> >>> dump $stuff->getAll()

for myself running with the argument --depth does not satisfy my object which is also rather large.  so we see that psysh has a dependency on symfony's var-dumper.

see: https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper

also: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html

the advanced section states

> The dump() function is just a thin wrapper and a more convenient way
> to call VarDumper::dump(). You can change the behavior of this
> function by calling VarDumper::setHandler($callable). Calls to dump()
> will then be forwarded to $callable.
>
> By adding a handler, you can customize the Cloners, Dumpers and
> Casters...

> A cloner is used to create an intermediate representation of any PHP
> variable. Its output is a Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Data
> object that wraps this representation...

> A cloner applies limits when creating the representation, so that one
> can represent only a subset of the cloned variable. Before calling
> cloneVar(), you can configure these limits:
>
> setMaxItems()
> Configures the maximum number of items that will be cloned past the minimum nesting depth. Items are counted using a breadth-first
> algorithm so that lower level items have higher priority than deeply
> nested items. Specifying -1 removes the limit. setMinDepth()
> Configures the minimum tree depth where we are guaranteed to clone all the items. After this depth is reached, only setMaxItems items
> will be cloned. The default value is 1, which is consistent with older
> Symfony versions. setMaxString()
> Configures the maximum number of characters that will be cloned before cutting overlong strings. Specifying -1 removes the limit.

see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/advanced.html

so what I am doing is creating a folder inside app named VarDumpFull then adding into file /app/VarDumpFull/VarDumpFull.php the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\VarDumpFull;

use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\VarCloner;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\CliDumper;

class VarDumpFull
{
        public function __construct($var)
        {
                $cloner = new VarCloner();
                $dumper = new CliDumper();
                $cloner->setMaxItems(-1);
                $cloner->setMaxString(-1);
                $dumper->dump($cloner->cloneVar($var));
        }
}
```

you can run this easily like so:

```
new VarDumpFull($variable_to_be_dumped);
```

remember to run to update your classes.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the collection to work with user property. If you want to do that in Tinker:

```
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    echo $customer->user->name;
}
```

If you just want to see the data structure, you can do this in Tinker:

```
$customers->first()->user
```

Comment: My question is how do I expand the user value where it has {#232 ...11}?

the code above is to simplify it but my relationship returns 1000s of rows that, for debugging I wonder if there is some command will allow me to access `{#232 ...11} id

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should load relationship:

```
$customers = App\Customer::with('user')->get();
```

but I assume you did it because you have user relationship visible on your output.

To get array representation of your customers together with relationships you should use:

```
foreach ($customers as $customer)
{
   dump($customer->toArray());
}
```

obviously result won't be the same as you dump the whole collection but you will get all model attributes together with relations and I think this is what you want here.

Comment: My question is how do I expand the user value where it has {#232 ...11}?

the code above is to simplify it but my relationship returns 1000s of rows that, for debugging I wonder if there is some command will allow me to access `{#232 ...11} id

Comment: @Kal Yes, I get it, but I was trying to do other things and no other worked for me