# Laravel "artisan tinker" stops with a colon (:)

Tags: laravel, tinker

[image]

When a lot of text is printed (example User::all()), old tinker v2.7.1 prints all data. The new tinker stops with a colon (:). Is there a way to return the old behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View nested objects under Tinker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946356/view-nested-objects-under-tinker)

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is a recent change in tinker. A bit older tinker version v2.7.1 prints all the data, but a newer version waits while you press the button to show more.

Comment: how do you stop the colon behavior?  I type my return key and it only shows one record at a time, and when I get to the last record, it shows END, and I cannot procede unless I exit out of tinker, and re-enter.

Answer (score 6):

Tinker uses Psysh.

Psysh has a config option for setting pager.

From https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/wiki/Config-options

> If this is not set, it falls back to less. It is recommended that you
> set up cli.pager in your php.ini with your preferred output pager.

For anything more than one page long, less will interrupt output with a colon.

I fixed this by switching the pager to 'cat'.

To update psysh options for tinker, create a `.psysh.php` file in the laravel project root directory and throw this in it:

```
<?php

return [
    'pager' => "cat"
];
```

Now when you run tinker, you'll get uninterrupted output (like it used to be).

Comment: You can set pager to `false` rather than `'cat'` and save yourself piping output to a new process every time :)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst setting pager to false does work for me (thanks to @bobthecow for the help with that in the comments) I wanted a solution that didn’t require adding .psysh.php to all my projects.

For anyone else who's experiencing this, as far as I can tell, it turns our that if you have never had the `pcntl` extension installed, Psysh has never used a pager: https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/blob/v0.11.20/src/Configuration.php#L1240

I had recently installed this and so everything started going through `less`. I prefer the previous behaviour in that all tinker output is in my actual terminal and shell, so I reverted to the previous behaviour by exporting the `TERM=dumb` variable.

I'm running in alpine on Docker so my existing `TERM` was `xterm`. No idea if this has any knock-on effects but so var it seemingly works as before installing the extension.

Comment: You can set it in `~/.config/psysh/config.php` rather than in each project individually.